# How to not italicize the footnote title in kableExtra?

Tags: r, kableextra

Footnote titles in kableExtra can be renamed but their standard format remains *italic*, as this is the default (see `?kableExtra::footnote()`).

```r
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
 kbl() %>%
 kable_styling() %>%
 footnote(general = "Foo, bar", general_title = "Take note:", footnote_as_chunk = T)
```

How can I not italicise the new `general_title` using `title_format`?

I tried `title_format = "normal"` but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an HTML table, you can use the `text_spec()` function and make use of the `extra_css` argument. You need to set `escape = FALSE` in the `footnote()` function so the code is interpreted and not printed.

```
library(kableExtra)

mtcars |>
  head() |>
  kbl() |>
  kable_styling() |>
  footnote(
    general = "Foo, bar",
    general_title = text_spec("Take note:", extra_css = "font-style: normal;"),
    footnote_as_chunk = TRUE,
    escape = FALSE
  )
```

[image]

I think it would be worthwhile making a feature request to have 'normal' as a font style option as it seems a strange decision to force bold/italics/underline.

Comment: Thanks and see here for the request: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/discussions/764